# retry jenkins kubernetes agent connection

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am using kubernetes plugin in Jenkins pipelines to create agents in kubernetes. I am able to launch, connect and do builds on the agents. However, when the agent pod doesn't have enough capacity, the agent bringup fails immediately with "forbidden: exceeded quota" error. My question is, is there a way to retry 'n' number of times with sleep time inbetween to bringup the agent as other builds running on kubernetes can finish and free up resources.

Thanks,
GD

Answer (score 0):

the kubernetes plugin version i was using is 1.27.7 and apparently this is a known bug in that version ( https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63976 ). the bug seems to be fixed on kubernetes plugin version 1.28.6.